# How to reinitialize hashicorp vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

I'm working on an automating a hashicorp vault process, and I need to repeatedly run the vault operator init command because of trial and error testing, I tried uninstalling vault and installing it again, but it seems like that doesn't remove the previous unseal keys + root token it generates, how can I do this?

I read somewhere that I needed to delete my storage "file" path which I already did but its not working (Actually my /opt/vault/data/ directory is empty), here is my vault.hcl file:

```
# Full configuration options can be found at 
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration

ui = true

#mlock = true
#disable_mlock = true

storage "file" {
  path = "/opt/vault/data"
}

#storage "consul" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
#  path    = "vault"
#}

# HTTP listener
#listener "tcp" {
#  address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
#  tls_disable = 1
#}

# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.crt"
  tls_key_file  = "/opt/vault/tls/tls.key"
}

# Enterprise license_path
# This will be required for enterprise as of v1.8
#license_path = "/etc/vault.d/vault.hclic"

# Example AWS KMS auto unseal
#seal "awskms" {
#  region = "us-east-1"
#  kms_key_id = "REPLACE-ME"
#}

# Example HSM auto unseal
#seal "pkcs11" {
#  lib            = "/usr/vault/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so"
#  slot           = "0"
#  pin            = "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD"
#  key_label      = "vault-hsm-key"
#  hmac_key_label = "vault-hsm-hmac-key"
#}
```

Comment: The root token should be saved in `~/.vault-token` so this file need to be removed too.

Comment: An easy way to reinitialize the service is using the containerized version: https://hub.docker.com/_/vault/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice for this type of setup is actually terraform or chef or any other stateful transformer.  That way you can bring the environment to an ideal state (terraform apply) and easily removed (terraform destroy).

To reinit vault, you can bring it down, delete the data folder: "/opt/vault/data" in your case.  Bring up another instance.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete /opt/vault/data
- Reboot your computer

(*You many also need to delete the file located at ~/.vault-token*)

Answer (score -3):

If you want to do the testing only why don't you use the vault in dev mode?